# How do I abstract away the .Net Core version number?

Tags: bash, .net-core

I have a bash script that calls my .Net Core app with a line like:

```
dotnet /path/to/my/project/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/myapp.dll "$@"
```

I have to keep updating my script whenever I upgrade my .Net Core version (e.g. **3.1**).  Is there a way to abstract that number away?

Comment: Cannot you simply use `dotnet run /path/to/my/project "$@"`?

Comment: @LexLi, Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.

Comment: It seems that your IDE puts your app here. How do you compile that?

Comment: Then more context is required to understand your actual setup. On a machine with .NET Core SDK (not merely the runtime) `dotnet run` is supposed to work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

cd to .csproj folder

```
dotnet run "$@"
```

or

```
cd /path/to/my/project/bin/Debug/*netcoreapp*
```

dotnet xxx.dll

Comment: I don't want to change the directory in the script because my .Net app needs to know the current directory